# How to send Data to a controller while navigating to a view

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-getx

I have this route

```
Get.toNamed('/community/discussion/${controller.community.topicId}}');
```

While navigating to the view, I want to pass the route parameter `topicId` to the view's controller so that it uses as document ID and load the content which will be stream to the view.

How can I send this parameter to the controller before the view's content is streamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're not using `Get.toNamed` the way it is supposed to.

Function `toNamed` takes a `dynamic` parameter `arguments` that you can use for your purpose.

In your source screen:

```
Get.toNamed<void>("/community/discussion/",
    arguments: {"topicId": controller.community.topicId});
```

In your destination screen:

```
var topicId = Get.parameters['topicId'];
```

Then you can easily set the topic id into your controller:

```
controller.topicId = topicId;

class YourController extends GetxController {
   int? topicId;
}
```

Comment: please what is the syntax of `int? topicId` for an sdk version lower than 2.12.0 ?

Comment: just remove the ? and assign an initial value

Comment: ok, i've tried but `topicId` at the level of the controller shows null

Comment: figured out what was wrong in my controller. thanks its working

Comment: can you tell me how did you fix the issue? Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to pass already lives in a GetX class, which it appears that it does, then you don't need to pass it at all. Anything that lives in a GetX class is already accessible from anywhere with `Get.find...`

Just access it on the next page with

```
Get.find<WhateverThisClassIsCalled>().community.topicId
```

Comment: Actually topicId is just an index obtained when iterating a stream. this index represent a documentId from firestore which i want to pass it to the controller of the next page so as to load the subcollection under this topicId.